# Commerce - add new tab to order page in control panel

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm am creating module that provides integration with shipping service for Craft commerce.

UX wise, it would be best if I could put module functionality in separate tab on order page. Mind you, I know that we can add new tabs using order fields functionality. But i wonder if it is possible to "hardcode" new tab using some php code. Some events maybe?

Answer (score 1):

This certainly used to be possible and was quite handy, but I believe since the commerce orders admin area moved to using Vue, there's no easy way to hook in and do this any more.

Would love to be proven wrong, though!